# Getting ARB subscription information from Authorize.net using Active Merchant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, automated-tests, authorize.net, activemerchant

I'm trying to write a test to verify the start date and interval of an Authorize.net ARB subscription created via Rails + Active Merchant.

I can successfully create the sub using `response = GATEWAY.recurring(...)` and a I get a success code.

After the subscription is created, however, as far as I can see from the Active Merchant documentation I can't really request any info, like the start date for instance.

The only methods available for ARB are:

`cancel_recurring`  `recurring`   `update_recurring`

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: the bounty is going to expire in 3 days and no answers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ARB API offers very limited reporting functionality. In fact all you can get through that API is the status of a subscription (ARBGetSubscriptionStatusRequest). The only other options available to you are to create (ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest), update (ARBUpdateSubscriptionRequest), and delete (ARBCancelSubscriptionRequest). This is not a RoR limitation. This is an API limitation. You can confirm this in the [ARB Guide](http://www.authorize.net/support/ARB_guide.pdf).

So, any information you want to keep track of related to a subscription (start date, end date, amount, etc) will need to be recorded by you in your database.

Authorize.Net does have a new [Transaction Detail API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/) which they are consistently enhancing. But as of right now it does not report the kind of information you are looking for.